# How to parent several cameras without adjusting one and interfering the others?

Tags: camera, parent

To make my outliner clean, I would like to make an empty parent to all similar objects. But when I set parent to all of my cameras, whenever I adjust one of them(with "lock camera to view"), the others move at the same time. This is really annoying that I lost my other angles every time!
[image]

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this while still keeping my outliner clean?

Answer (score 1):

Parenting should not be used as an organization method for the outliner, it is a scene hierarchy system and has obvious implications in the 3D view as you've already experienced.

Use groups instead by grouping objects together and using the outliner in *Groups* mode so you can have objects in "categories" or "folders" without affecting their behavior.

A [proper layer system](https://developer.blender.org/T38384) is [being worked on](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Julianeisel/GSoC-2016/Weekly_Reports) for the upcoming Blender 2.8 but it is still far off

Comment: I have an issue regarding activating cameras and doing multiple renderings. Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108064/changing-active-camera-will-yield-an-incorrect-rendering)? It seems that I am doing everything correctly but the result that I get is so weirdly strange. I need some urgent help and I think you might be able to help me with it. Really appreciate you.